# Interpretation of partial dependence plot for explanatory variables with different distributions

Tags: random-forest, partial-dependency-plots

I've fit a random forest regression model to predict a continuous landscape metric *y*. One of the explanatory variables in the model is continuous (Longitude), while another is categorical (Class) with two levels (Class 1, Class 2). Class 1 has a higher mean *y* and observations that are evenly distributed across the longitudinal range of the study. Class 2 has a lower mean *y* and observations that are geographically clustered; specifically, there are no Class 2 observations for longitudes greater than 50°.

After training the model, I generated a partial dependence plot to look at the effect of longitude on the predicted landscape metric by Class. I'm confused as to how to interpret the results. There were no Class 2 training observations for the geographical area (> 50°) that shows the highest predicted values. I thought the model might be overfitting, but no amount of hyperparameter tuning has changed the general pattern of the classes. I'd appreciate any insights from more experienced random forest users!

[image]